# How do I setup O365 to allow IMAP? (App Passwords no found)

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365, office365, microsoft-365

I have an office365 account and cannot link my email to my email client. I have MFA activated and the only client that allows me to link the mail is the same Outlook 2019 for PC or Mac.

Can I link you with other clients or mail managers?
I have followed this guide.
[How do I setup O365 to allow IMAP?](https://serverfault.com/questions/950589/how-do-i-setup-o365-to-allow-imap)

I have IMAP enabled
I have application passwords
I have the correct servers, IMAP and SMTP

I was finding out and I think there is something more to do.

https://alberthoitingh.com/2018/04/26/multi-factor-authentication-beware/

[image]

Does anyone know how to allow linking office365 with any mail client in IMAP?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my knowledge, IMAP4 is enabled for all users in Exchange Online by default. Then you could create a new outlook profile to Setup Your Office365 Account with outlook Using IMAP. I have tested in my lab, you could refer to:
[image][image]